# How do I specify HTTP or HTTPS dependent on the current URL?

Tags: javascript, https

My code specifies

```
this._restUrl = "http://" + this._info.host + "/app/rest/";
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to make it use "https://" when using SSL. How can I turn this into an http or https statement? This works fine for http as it is.

Comment: You could also do `window.location.protocol + "//" + this._info...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a relative protocol:

```
this._restUrl = "//" + this._info.host + "/app/rest/";
```

[Here’s a good description of those.](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

Comment: I just searched and found that page after your post. Thank You VERY much! I couldn't find a name for what I was looking for. That was way too simple!